# Django: Allow choice of many OneToOneFields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a system whereby the user can have one of 3 account types (Musician, Blogger or Listener). I have accomplished this but I am not sure this is the best way to go about it.

### Current Solution

In the current system I have a custom user model with a CharField `account_type` that has a choices attribute of `'M', 'L', or 'B'` for the three account_types. There are three models for Blogger, Musician and Listener. I use signals to assign the account_type after account creation.

User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    A copy of the django default user model with additional account_type and email used as username.

    Password, account_type and email are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    ACCOUNT_TYPES = (
        ('M', 'Musician'),
        ('B', 'Blogger'),
        ('L', 'Listener')
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES, default='L')
    ...
```

Receivers.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='associate_account_type_post_save')
def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        AccountType(instance).associate(instance.account_type)


@receiver(user_signed_up)
def user_signed_up_receiver(request, user, **kwargs):
    AccountType(user).associate(user.account_type)
```

`AccountType(user).associate(account_type)` is a helper function that first checks if the user has a relation to one of the account types, deletes it if so and then creates the new relation. I don't think the code for that is relevant to the question so have not included.

The two receivers are required because of the use of allauth. Since I have added a column to the User model I also created a custom form with the account_type choices field. Allauth triggers the `user_signed_up` signal after two saves; first the model is created with the standard form fields, then the custom form fields are saved. I have to use the post_save signal as well to make sure that the relation I also set when the user is created through Django's admin interface.

### Alternative solution

It would be good not to have two receivers that ultimately have the same function and not to have a column that is redundant. A good alternative would be to have a field within the user model that does not have a corresponding column but a corresponding relation. Therefore, no string of `'M', 'B', or 'L'` is saved to the database but a relationship is automatically created.

This way one can query whether the user is a musician simply by `User.musician` and catching a `DoesNotExist` exception.

The only method I can think of to accomplish this is if the request were included in signals. That way I could have the same receiver and just replace `user.account_type` with `request.cleaned_data['account_type']`.

I am not sure if this can be accomplished in Django and hope someone can enlighten me.